# Removing Look Up field link in visualforce page

Tags: lookup

I am displaying Lookup field value in apex:commanLink.
but its link is navigating to the master record .
i want to remove this link,How should i implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you just want to show plain text instead?

Comment: no i want to give some other link on thet instead of by default link of Master record.

Comment: I just noticed your using apex:commandLink, so the link will be to a method on your controller class. That method will be determining what happens when the user clicks the link. It may help to share some sample code in your question btw.

Comment: Please consider including a snippet from your visualforce to help us understand what you're doing now and what you're trying to change.

Comment: hi,where you are showing that look up value just show its name suppose your lookup field value is look__c so just use lookup__r.Name.definitely work!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to show `Name` field of the related object instead of just lookup field on the referencing one.

Supposing your lookup field API name is `look__c` - just use `lookup__r.Name`. Definitely works!!!

Comment: Can you mark your own answer as accepted so it goes "off the radar" of unanswered questions? :)

Comment: It was listed in a review menu (system flags some too short answers as suspicious and at 1000+ you're expected to care about the site, fix simple code formatting or grammar problems). There was nothing wrong with the core of your answer, it's just a bit more readable and useful for whoever else has same problem :)

Comment: okz will take care from next time

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple link you are looking for use `<apex:outputLink>` instead. If you need to call a controller then stick with `<apex:commandLink>` but set the PageReference appropriately as the return value of your method (returning null should stop you navigating anywhere).